# Visio add-in crashes, Faulting module name: ntdll.dll

Tags: crash, add-in, visio

I have created Visio (VSTO) Com Add-in.
After one of my users installed Visio 2016, Visio with the following error:
"Visio is running into problems with the '[add in name]' add-in.
If this keeps happening, disable this add-in and check the available updates.
Do you want to disable it now?"

I not sure it's got to do with Visio 2016 only, but we've tried reinstall both 32/64 bit
(on Windows 10 64 bit operating system)

**

- Here's what I've seen in the "Event Viewer"

**:
Faulting application name: VISIO.EXE, version: 16.0.11328.20368, time stamp: 0x5d173494
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.17763.1158, time stamp: 0x67e7a2b6
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x000e0e03
Faulting process id: 0x2c58
Faulting application start time: 0x01d637f389d9c14d
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\VISIO.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 3d86d759-b344-4d14-9487-1078fb895664
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

I've done deep debugging and the location is random,
but I have noticed that in many cases the crash is at "save" location:
this.Application.ActiveDocument.Save();

I've done lots of web research and so far didn't find meaningful information.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Does your user have other Visio add-ins installed? The crash used to be a common issue with Visio Bluetooth add-in installed by some video card drivers.

Comment: No. the only Add-In is the one I've created. Nothing to do with Bluetooth add-in. I'd like to know if there is known Visio - ntdll.dll compatibility known issue?

Comment: ntdll.dll is basically a part of the operating system. There cannot be any "incompatibility" with it. The crash message basically means that something has corrupted memory in Visio. Another common reason for such crash (apart from the bluetooth add-in) is developing against different version of Visio than your client has installed (i.e. if the add-in uses some feature of Visio that does not exist in the clients' Visio version). Like, you have 2019 installed and your client has 2007.

Comment: By the way, it is a good idea to have logging and exception handling. And have all your code called from Visio wrapped in a try - catch blocks (i.e. event handlers, Startup / Shutdown, etc).

Comment: Hi Nikolay and thanks for your response. I am developing using .Net Framework 4.5.2 on top of Visio 2013 32 bit / 2016 32/64 bit. Most of our users can work fluently with no problems while 2 workstation (using Visio 2016 32/64 bit fails). That's why I suspect that it's about compatibility. All my code is wrapped by try/catch. I do have trace log and I saw that it almost all crash on Document.Save() (or just right after...)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe out of your scope but I had same error without Visio add-in or whatever

Fix this by going to File - Options - Advanced in Visio, and checking out the "Disable Enhanced Metafile optimization" box to disable this option, under Display

source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/767543/visio-crashes-when-opening-file.html

worked fine for me

Rémi